# The program is detecting the switch various times instead of one (Issue with polling)

Tags: c, embedded, microcontroller

I'm writing code for an ATMega328P microcontroller and am unsure of how to bypass the issue mentioned in the title.

Comment: You need "debouncing"? There is a lot of material about that, and SO questions too. The techniques derive from detecting *transitions* or "changes in state" and even if debouncing isn't needed, you still have to detect transitions, not the actual state.

Comment: Without knowing what you do it is hard to detect what you do wrong. You might have some simple bug in your code or you might need to add some debouncing mechanism

Comment: How do I debounce using a short and simple delay?

Comment: As commented, there is plenty of [material](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=c+stackoverflow+debounce+site:stackoverflow.com) to research. But the first thing is to make sure your polling routine detects the *transitions*. Until you do that you won't know if debouncing is necessary.

Comment: I'm not sure how to implement any of those since I'm a beginner. If I share my work would I be able to receive help

Comment: If you are polling for a key closure *state*, it stays closed until released and a simple poll keeps telling you it is closed. So you need to remember the *previous* state and detect when it *changes*.

Answer (score 0):

As i understand instead of detecting a single transition you are detecting multiple transitions, this is because the controller is polling at much higher rate so it detects the transition multiple times.

To prevent this, you need a mechanism to make sure a single transition is held in a given state for certain period of time. This mechanism is called de-bouncing. Other advantage of this method is it will prevent/filter out mechanical noise.

Some are the links below which will explain this better:
https://www.arduino.cc/en/tutorial/debounce

Hope this helps..!
https://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/debouncing